# Re-setting Logstash state

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am currently under development and using the following configuration for a logstash agent:

```
input {
  file {
    type => "access_log"

    # Wildcards work, here :)
    path => [ "/root/isaac/vuforia_logs/access_logs/gw_access_log.2014-02-19.00.log"]

    start_position => "beginning"
  }


} 

filter {
 if [type] == "access_log" {
  grok { 
    pattern  => "\[%{DATA:my_timestamp}\] %{IP:client} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} \[%{DATA:auth_data}\] \[%{DATA:another_timstamp}\] %{NUMBER:result_code} %{NUMBER:duration} %{NUMBER:bytes}"
  }
 }
}



output {
  stdout { debug => true }
  elasticsearch_http { 
        host => "192.168.79.128"
        }
```

The very first time it reads the file, it will process it and log to stdout and elasticsearch. The problem is when I restart logstash it does not do anything which I presume is because it kept the last position where logstash stopped last time. I am interesting in resetting logstash such that it would re-process the file from the beginning. This is for development and testing purposes, is there a way to reset/clean the logstash state?

Thx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Logstash will record a sincedb for the input file. The default path is your $HOME directory. You can visit [here](http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.3/inputs/file#sincedb_path) for more information.

If you want to reset/clean it, you can delete all the .sincedb_* in your $HOME. Then when you restart logstash, it will read from the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

For those who got here with `jdbc`, you need `last_run_metadata_path`.

Ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#plugins-inputs-jdbc-last_run_metadata_path

Comment: this just saved me!